# ¿En una aplicación de consola tipo .Net Framework de Visual Basic .Net es posible lanzarla en modo silencioso?

Tags: vb.net, consola

### Es decir quiero que se ejecute pero que durante la ejecución no se vea la consola (la pantalla negra).

Cabe mencionar que tengo instalado Windows 10 y VS 2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes usar la clase ProcessStartInfo para especificar la propiedad WindowStyle como ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden al iniciar el proceso, para que la consonla se oculte.

Asi:

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("programa.exe")
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Process.Start(startInfo)
```